# Merging multiple LAS files using Python?

Tags: python, merge, las

Is it possible to merge multiple LAS files into one using Python? Currently I'm parsing LAS data from a website. So the way I'm currently getting this to work is by, getting a bounding box around a certain address which you can input. I give this coordinates to the website where the las data is located. I then check which las files are located at that location and download the different tiles available. I do this by checking the website via beautiful soup and parse the download link to a request. It's not ascii data and i'm not reading the las files in Python for visualization. But my question is : When I get the different las files that are representing the tile from the specific location, is there a possible way to merge it ? I would love to merge these into one big LAS file that I can open in CloudCompare. Is there a library I need to know about. Or should I look at LasTools? If so how do  implement this into my Python script.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your clarifications. with lastools you can do `las2las -i file1.las file2.las file3.las -merged -o merged.las`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on how to implement this in my python script?

Comment: I don't know for python but `las2las` does the job well so no need to reinvent the wheel in my opinion.

Comment: You can use `subprocess.call()` to run what @JRR suggests via Python (or `check_output` or `Popen` depending on your needs).  It's also possible using laspy, but if the las version / record format / vlrs don't match between all of your files then it's a bit more work to implement.